# Get all member from a specific group in an AD

Tags: php, active-directory

I am trying to get all member from certain group in the AD.

Here is the AD screenshot:
[image]

And this is the search filter I tried with other variants.

```
$ldap->search(
'(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=CN=INFOCMS_BBC,DC=OBS,DC=MADRID))', 
array("distinguishedName", "userPrincipalName", "sAMAccountName", "displayName",  "memberof"), 
"OU=OBS-Website");
```

I was reading other related post and tried to apply what I have found, but without success.

I would appreciate one help here.